# Web scraping into R multiple links with similar URL using a for loop or lapply

Tags: html, r, for-loop, web-scraping, lapply

This code scrapes from here http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2015_sched.htm every Date that contains Employment Situation under the Release column.

```
pg <- read_html("http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2015_sched.htm")

# target only the <td> elements under the bodytext div
body <- html_nodes(pg, "div#bodytext")

# we use this new set of nodes and a relative XPath to get the initial <td> elements, then get their siblings
es_nodes <- html_nodes(body, xpath=".//td[contains(., 'Employment Situation for')]/../td[1]")

# clean up the cruft and make our dates!
nfpdates2015 <- as.Date(trimws(html_text(es_nodes)), format="%A, %B %d, %Y")

###thanks @hrbrmstr for this###
```

I would like to repeat that for other URLs, containing other years, named in the same way with only the year number changing. Particularly, for the following URLs:

```
#From 2008 to 2015
http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2015_sched.htm
http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2014_sched.htm
...
http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2008_sched.htm
```

My knowledge of `rvest`, `HTML` and `XML` is almost non-existent. I thought to apply the same code with a for loop, but my efforts were futile. Of course I could just repeat the code for 2015 eight times to get all years, it would neither take too long nor too much space. Yet I am very curious to know how this could be done in a more efficient way. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a loop you would change the `url` string using a `paste0` statment

```
for(i in 2008:2015){

  url <- paste0("http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/", i, "_sched.htm")
  pg <- read_html(url)

  ## all your other code goes here.

}
```

Or using an `lapply` to return a list of the results.

```
lst <- lapply(2008:2015, function(x){
  url <- paste0("http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/", x, "_sched.htm")

  ## all your other code goes here.
  pg <- read_html(url)

  # target only the <td> elements under the bodytext div
  body <- html_nodes(pg, "div#bodytext")

  # we use this new set of nodes and a relative XPath to get the initial <td> elements, then get their siblings
  es_nodes <- html_nodes(body, xpath=".//td[contains(., 'Employment Situation for')]/../td[1]")

  # clean up the cruft and make our dates!
  nfpdates <- as.Date(trimws(html_text(es_nodes)), format="%A, %B %d, %Y")
  return(nfpdates)
})
```

Which returns

```
 lst
[[1]]
 [1] "2008-01-04" "2008-02-01" "2008-03-07" "2008-04-04" "2008-05-02" "2008-06-06" "2008-07-03" "2008-08-01" "2008-09-05"
[10] "2008-10-03" "2008-11-07" "2008-12-05"

[[2]]
 [1] "2009-01-09" "2009-02-06" "2009-03-06" "2009-04-03" "2009-05-08" "2009-06-05" "2009-07-02" "2009-08-07" "2009-09-04"
[10] "2009-10-02" "2009-11-06" "2009-12-04"

## etc...
```

Comment: Thank you Symbolix! Both methods work great, and `lapply` is considerably faster. Yet neither records a variable with the dates for all 8 years (or 8 different variables). In both cases `nfpdates` only stores the last year (i.e. 2015). How could this be achieved?

Comment: @Gracos the `lapply` returns a list (of length 8). If you assign the `lapply` to a varaible you can then access all the returned results. See my update.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with `sprintf` (with no loops)

```
url <- sprintf("http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/%d_sched.htm", 2008:2015)
url
#[1] "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2008_sched.htm" "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2009_sched.htm"
#[3] "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2010_sched.htm" "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2011_sched.htm"
#[5] "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2012_sched.htm" "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2013_sched.htm"
#[7] "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2014_sched.htm" "http://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/2015_sched.htm"
```

and if we need to read the links

```
library(rvest)
lst <-  lapply(url, function(x) {

   pg <- read_html(x)
   body <- html_nodes(pg, "div#bodytext")
   es_nodes <- html_nodes(body, xpath=".//td[contains(., 'Employment Situation for')]/../td[1]")

   nfpdates <- as.Date(trimws(html_text(es_nodes)), format="%A, %B %d, %Y")
   nfpdates
  })

head(lst, 3)
#[[1]]
# [1] "2008-01-04" "2008-02-01" "2008-03-07" "2008-04-04" "2008-05-02" "2008-06-06" "2008-07-03" "2008-08-01"
# [9] "2008-09-05" "2008-10-03" "2008-11-07" "2008-12-05"

#[[2]]
# [1] "2009-01-09" "2009-02-06" "2009-03-06" "2009-04-03" "2009-05-08" "2009-06-05" "2009-07-02" "2009-08-07"
# [9] "2009-09-04" "2009-10-02" "2009-11-06" "2009-12-04"

#[[3]]
# [1] "2010-01-08" "2010-02-05" "2010-03-05" "2010-04-02" "2010-05-07" "2010-06-04" "2010-07-02" "2010-08-06"
# [9] "2010-09-03" "2010-10-08" "2010-11-05" "2010-12-03"
```

Comment: Thanks very much akrun, much appreciated. Your answer is almost identical to Symbolix's, I'll accept his as came in first. I'm out of upvotes for the following 20 hours.

Comment: @Gracos Yes, it is the `paste` vs `sprintf`.  Otherwise, you have almost done all the groundwork

Comment: @akrun off the top of your head, do you know of any benefit to using either of `sprintf` or `paste0`?

Comment: @Symbolix I don't think there is any difference in speed, but with `sprintf`, you can use it on a single string, while with `paste0` we are pasting multiple substrings together.